# SQL Server 2008 - how to export several tables via command line (result should be "insert into" script)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server database, and I want to export some of the tables into a .sql file (insert into statements) from the command line (not via a wizard, there are lots of tables I want to export and I want to be able to do this by one click).

How can this be done? I only saw commands that allow an entire db backup, but I'm allowed to export only some of the tables.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Try using [SQL Server Dumper](http://www.ruizata.com/); it's got a lot of options and can really come in handy. A few features:

- Foreign Keys: order tables in text file in order to insert data without colisions/errors
- Primary Key IDENTITY: guarantees the value of the IDENTITY field
- Reference to itself: eliminates the constraint and at the end create it again

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on how to do it via command line? (without external tools?)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a command line tool, consider taking a look at the redate tool suite (sql data compare in particular), and it makes these operations trivially easy to do. There is a fully functional, 14 day free trial.